# Twig Unexpected token "name" of value "same" ("end of print statement" expected)

Tags: twig

I'm getting this error in my Twig template:
*Unexpected token "name" of value "same" ("end of print statement" expected).*

I have an XML file where the user can toggle the background color on or off. On will trigger a "yellow" css class which makes the background yellow and off will have it look blue (standard color). The "yellow" class needs to be added to the  as a class.

I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong.. Here's my XML:

```
                <property name="background_color" type="checkbox">
                    <meta>
                        <info_text lang="en">When the toggle is switched off, the default background color is blue.</info_text>
                        <title lang="en">Yellow background</title>
                    </meta>

                    <params>
                        <param name="type" value="toggler"/>
                    </params>
                </property>
```

And here is my Twig file:

```
{% embed 'includes/pattern_section.html.twig' with {
'section_class': 'pattern-block',
'background_color': block.background_color} %}
```

And here is the pattern_section.html.twig file:

```
{% block body %}
<section class="{{ section_class | default('') }} {{ background_color same as (true) ? 'yellow' : '' }}">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                Content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The correct syntax is `background_color is same as (true)`

Comment: Yes that was it! Thanks!